NextAuth.js Adding more data to session
I have an callback inside my next auth api for session in which I'm getting user data from database, which works fine, but the session is called multiple times when the user is browsing the website, so it is overflowing the database. So I want to somehow modify the session, so it doesn't have to call the database every time, but store the user data in the session itself, either store the user data when signed in or first time the session is called, but I am unsuccessful so far.
This is function which works fine, but every time the session is called, there is a call to database:
    async session({ session }) {
      const { user: { image, email }} = session
      const provider = image.includes('google') ? 'google' : 'facebook'
      const account = (await getAccountsFromDb({ email, type: provider }))[0]
      return account
    },

I tried multiple things, f.e. this, but in the next session there is no session.account
    async session({ session }) {
      const { user: { image, email }} = session
      const provider = image.includes('google') ? 'google' : 'facebook'
      const account = (await getAccountsFromDb({ email, type: provider }))[0]
      session.account = account
      return account
    },


What is the need to get user data from database again. It should be available in the session. right?

There is only a small amount of data in the session itself, I need more data to store in the session. It would be enough to store the email and the hashed password, so I can fetch the data on fe and do it only once, not everytime the session changes.

I did not understood 100% but you could add a condition like if (!session.account) { //do db call and store data in session.account }

Yes, that was my initial thought, but I'm trying to say, that if I store something in session (f.e. session.account), it would not be there in the next session call, the session.account is always undefined.

because in the callback you need to return the session whereas you are returning account

That is not correct, even if I return session, in the next session call there is no account property.
async session({ session }) {       const { user: { image, email }} = session       const provider = image.includes('google') ? 'google' : 'facebook'       if (!session.account) {         console.log('Call to DB')         const account = (await getAccountsFromDb({ email, type: provider }))[0]         session.account = account       }       return session     },
Every time the session is called, the console log is printed, so the db call is made aswell, which is the problem

I found out the answer, you can't change the session, but you can change the token inside jwt, so this code is working how I wanted now.
    async jwt({ token }) {
      const { picture, email } = token
      const provider = picture.includes('google') ? 'google' : 'facebook'
      if (!token.account) {
        const account = (await getAccountsFromDb({ email, type: provider }))[0]
        token.account = account
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ token }) {
      return token.account
    },

